# Allow only positive decimal numbers

Tags: python, django

Within my Django models I have created a decimal field like this:

```
price = models.DecimalField(_(u'Price'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12)
```

Obviously it makes no sense for the price to be negative or zero.  Is there a way to limit the decimal number to only positive numbers?

Or do I have to capture this using form validation?

Comment: Why you use: _(u'Price') ? What does it mean?

Comment: The question was from 10 years ago with Python 2.7.  You don't have to worry about u'' anymore.  It stands for unicode.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use the [`MinValueValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator).

```
price = models.DecimalField(_(u'Price'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))])
```

Comment: Or you could just add `min_value=Decimal('0.01')`

Comment: That works for form fields, but I haven't tested `min_value=Decimal('0.01')` for a model field. It isn't documented in the [model field docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/).

Comment: I stand corrected. My comment answers the last question about form validation. `min_value` does not work on models.DecimalField.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but could be more complete with this:
`from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator`
`from decimal import Decimal`

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this :

```
# .....
class priceForm(ModelForm):
    price = forms.DecimalField(required=False, max_digits=6, min_value=0)
```

This, also, is responsible for the validator value of 'price'.

Answer (score 3):

In Django 2.2 you can [add constraints to a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints) which will be applied in the migrations as a constraint on the database table:

```py
from decimal   import Decimal
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField( _(u'Price'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12 )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(price__gt=Decimal('0')), name='price_gt_0'),
        ]
```

[Note:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/)

> **Validation of Constraints**
>
> In general constraints are not checked during `full_clean()`, and do not raise `ValidationErrors`. Rather you’ll get a database integrity error on `save()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your product model, and you want to add non-negative constraint on price field. You can add the meta constraint on the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'product'
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(price__gte='0'), name='product_price_non_negative'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Import dependencies

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
```

2. Add validators

```py
price = models.DecimalField(
 decimal_places=2, 
 max_digits=12, 
 validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, it seems that there's no way to put something like a database constraint on a field.  The best you can do is add model "validators" which will be called if you call model validation or use a `ModelForm`.  The validators are skipped if you simply put values into an object and `save()`.

So, you can add validation on the forms or you can add validation to the model which also get run on the form level if you use `ModelForm`.

From the [docs on "How validators are run"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run):

> See the [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/) for more information on how validators are run
>   in forms, and [Validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) for how they’re run in models. Note
>   that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model,
>   but if you are using a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm), it will run your validators on any
>   fields that are included in your form. See the [ModelForm documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/)
>   for information on how model validation interacts with forms.

Comment: Spot on. If you want this validation to fire when creating the object in db. Override the `save()` method of the model to run `self.full_clean()`