# How do I enforce a positive number on my Python/Django model field?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model, numbers

I'm using Django and Python 3.7. I'm also using Postgres 9.6. I have the following field in my model.

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    ...
    score = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)
```

Is there any way to write constraints such that when my migration is generated, the underlying database will enforce a `FloatField` that is always equal to or greater than zero? I don't want any negative numbers in this field.

Comment: As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12384584/10938791), you should use: MinValueValidator.
Go check.

Comment: That does not answer the question.  That applies the validator but does not do anything to enforce the constraint at the database level, at least not with the type of database I'm using.  Go check.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no `PositiveFloatField` in Django, but you can use [`MinValueValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.MinValueValidator).

`MinValueValidator` is [implemented like this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/65b880b7268dd8fe97fde5af77bede46305eb499/django/core/validators.py#L386-L392):

```py
class MinValueValidator(BaseValidator):
    message = _('Ensure this value is greater than or equal to %(limit_value)s.')
    code = 'min_value'

    def compare(self, a, b):
        return a < b  # super simple.
```

Append the validator to your float field.

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    po_float = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]

m = YourModel(po_float=-1)
m.clean_fields()  # raise ValidationError
```

**Note**: Django validation does not run automatically. So you must run `obj.clean_fields()` or `obj.clean()`. Check [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

Comment: Thanks for this information.  Per my comment to the other guy, I was wondering if there was a way to run the migration and have the postiive constraint enforced by PostGres.  When I tried adding the MinValidator, no new constraints were added to the PostGres table.

Comment: Validator is the logic of django and is independent of database. As I said in the answer, since there is no PositiveFlotField, it will be difficult to set up database through django. @Dave

Comment: That includes 0.0, right? (greater than or equal) - how would you enforce it to be greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but in case anyone is looking, add a `CheckConstraint` to the `model.Meta` to define the DB constraint.  A `MinValueValidator` should be used, (as discussed in other answers) to catch invalid values before attempting to save them to DB.

So a complete solution to OP might be something like:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    ...
    score = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False, MinValueValidator(0))

class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(score__gte=0), name="score_gte_0"),
    ]
```